# Generate SSL certificates in iOS App programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, soap, openssl

I am building an application which has to access a SOAP API and I need to implement XML-Encryption for WS-Security. Therefore each copy of the application has to generate its certificates for that. Now, the API has also the ability to work as certificate authority(CA). So what I need to do is:

1. generate the client certificate on the device
2. generate the certificate sign request and send it over the api to the server
3. obtain the signed certificate through the API in the response of the previous request
4. the server API should then use my public key (which it has obtained through the CSR) and use it for the encryption

Is this scenario possible? I am thinking about using the openssl library as it can be ported to iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Use [MYCrypto](https://github.com/snej/MYCrypto) for generation certificates on client